# Ember: Passing localisation key to component template

Tags: ember.js, ember-i18n

I have a modal-dialog component template, which contains the following

```
  <div class="header">
    {{t title}}
  </div>
```

So, I am using the ember-i18n [1] library to add localisation to ember. Now I am calling that component template from the actual modal dialog template:

```
{{#modal-dialog title="dialog.title"}}
  <h3 class="flush--top">I am a modal dialog</h5>
  <button {{action "close"}}>Done</button>
{{/modal-dialog}}
```

What I am trying to do here is, defining a key that is used for localisation in the dialog template, which is passed to the component template and translated there. However, this leads to the following error: `Missing translation: title`. So the variable title just seems to actually be treated as a string and not as a variable.

Alternatively I could translate the title in the dialog template and pass it to the component template:

dialog:

```
{{#modal-dialog title={{t "dialog.title"}} action="close"}}
```

That leads to a compiler error:

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
...#modal-dialog title={{t "dialog.title"}}
-----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'INTEGER', 'BOOLEAN', 'OPEN_SEXPR', 'ID', 'DATA', got 'OPEN'
```

Is there any way to make this happen?

[1] https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mitchlloyd presented a great solution here: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/need-to-pass-a-value-from-component-template-to-component/5792/6

Use the Translation suffix in the template (I was just passing a title property):

```
{{#modal-dialog action="close" titleTranslation="modal.title"}}
  <h3 class="flush--top">Name Change Modal</h5>
{{/modal-dialog}}
```

The component uses the Mixin from ember-i18n:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend(Em.I18n.TranslateableProperties, {
});
```

And finally in the template, just reference the translated title property:

```
<div class="title"> {{title}}</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The explanations above are not working with the latest version of ember-i18n where TranslateableProperties [has been removed](https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n/blob/master/Changelog.md#400-alpha):

Here is how I made it work with ember-i18n 4.x and ember-cli 1.13.1:

1 - Make sure that the service `i18n` is injected in your component:

```
//initializers/i18n.js
export default {
  name: 'i18n',

  after: 'ember-i18n',

  initialize: function(_, app) {
      app.inject('controller', 'i18n', 'service:i18n');
      app.inject('component', 'i18n', 'service:i18n');
  }
};
```

2 - The component's template references a `{{title}}` property:

```
//templates/components/pick-card.hbs
!-- Selection of the card -->
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 40px;">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h1 class="panel-title">{{title}}</h1>
            </div>
...
```

3 - The template where I call my component:

```
//templates/security/forgot-username.hbs
{{#pick-card title-i18n="page.forgot_username"}}
{{/pick-card}}
```

4 - The component's controller where the magic is:

```
    import Ember from 'ember';
    import {translationMacro as t} from "ember-i18n";

    export default Ember.Component.extend({
      title: Ember.computed('i18n.locale', function() {
          return this.get('i18n').t(this.get('title-i18n'));
      })
    });
```

As described in [ember-i18n doc](https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n/wiki/Doc:-Translating-Text) the use of
`i18n.locale` is crucial to make sure that the property `{{title}}` is translated automatically as soon as the user changes the locale.

Have fun :)

Answer (score 1):

Better way is to use the Handlebars Subexpressions:

You would use some this like this:

```
{{#modal-dialog title=(tv "dialog.title") action="close"}}
```

Here **tv** is the helper i have used:

And You need to register a helper for this:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('tv', function (key) {
  return Em.I18n.t(key);
});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can compute that title property within the controller or model. So:

```
{{#modal-dialog title={{t "dialog.title"}} action="close"}}
```

Would be:

```
{{#modal-dialog title="dialog.translateTitle" action="close"}}
```

And then you could have a computed property like so:

```
translateTitle: function () {
  return this.translateLibraryMethodYouUse(this.get('title'));
}.property('title')
```

That is obviously psuedo code, but it should work if you can get your localization into the `translateTitle` property. you can put that in your dialog model, or you can put it into your item controller or whatever you are using for that context.

UPDATE::

Okay, so took a look at that library. You can also try updating your controller or model with the `Em.I18n.TranslateableProperties` mixin to allow you to bind a translated property:

```
App.DialogController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(Em.I18n.TranslateableProperties, {
  titleTranslation: 'dialog.title'
});
```

Good luck, and hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, I tried to get that going using what you described, however everything broke when I was trying to either access the value I have  in the component-template from the component, or when I was trying to access the value that is set in a controller from the component-template. I have written more about these issues here: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/need-to-pass-a-value-from-component-template-to-component/5792

Answer (score 0):

Just to update the responses here to be a little more up to date! As mentioned by @mohamedjahabersadiq, you can use Subexpressions. These also work fine in HTMLBars (>= Ember 1.10.0). However, you don't have to register a new helper, you can use the existing `t` helper from ember-i18n.

```
{{#modal-dialog title=(t "dialog.title")}}
    Hello
{{/modal-dialog}}
```